# "sys.argv[x]" is out of range

Tags: python, command-line, user-input

I must run the exact command:

```
python3 main.py flip pattern.ppm > flippedpattern.ppm
```

on the following code:

```
def main(args):
    if sys.argv[1] == "flip":
        fileName = sys.argv[2]
        method = read_ppm(fileName)
        print(method.flip())
        return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

I have a ppm file and I am trying to manipulating it using another module, but it keeps telling me sys.argv[4] is out of range when assigning it to the variable 'outputFile'

The code executed should be essentially this for the flip command

```
method = "flip"
method = read_ppm("pattern.ppm")
f.write(method.flip())
```

Doing exactly that using the repl in visual studio leads to success but when I try to run it from the command line through the main module it doesn't work.  Why is this?  Does the '>' character somehow interfere with sys.argv or am I making a clear counting mistake that I can't see?

The else statement would account for the input not catching and simply printing, using the input

```
python3 main.py flip pattern.ppm
```

without any file redirect.

Comment: That makes sense. Inspect the contents of `sys.argv` if it does not - you'll see that it has a length of 3 (or 4?) in any case, `argv[4]` is invalid as 4 is out of range. (Note that `>` and after are *not* part of the command-line arguments.)

Comment: How do I capture the output filename then?

Comment: `method = "flip"; method = read_ppm()` makes no sense. What is the purpose of the first assignment?

Comment: It was leftover from a previous way I was trying to implement the code, my apologies.

Comment: apparently you have edited your question, because `but it keeps telling me sys.argv[4]` there is no `sys.argv[4]` in the code. Therefore I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Ok. As @user2864740 pointed out you are being subjected to the way the shell parses your command. The `>` is not an argument, it is a redirect. So if you want to be able to know the name of the output file you will have to provide it as an argument. If you want to be able to do both [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) can help you gain some expressive power beyond using `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument after > is not part of the command line passed to python.  It is the file that the shell writes standard output to.  So, for example, `print "Hello"` will write Hello to flippedpattern.ppm.

If you want flippedpattern.ppm to be the fourth command line argument, just leave out the > in the call.  (Then, standard output will be written to the screen.)

Edit: Given your modified description, you can write `sys.stdout.write(method.flip())`.  The only difference between this and `print(method.flip())` is that print adds a newline character at the end of the string, while .write doesn't.

Comment: So how can I grab that name then to grab any filename used?

Comment: @somebody You can't "grab" anything after `>` - the *redirect* is handled by the shell. If you want it, don't use the redirect.

Comment: To clarify, python doesn't know (or care) whether it's writing to the screen or to a file when you call print (or sys.stdout.write).  The shell/OS handle that.

Comment: So I should delete basically from the method assignment down to the creation of the instance and leave the rest?  Like I have edited the code to?

Comment: I think so, although I forget what the original code was.  Another option is just to assign the file handle in your original code to sys.stdout.  E.g. `outputFile = sys.stdout`.  You can then just pass outputFile around, and call outputFile.write(...).  The only thing you can't do is find out the file name.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with using stdout.  Could you edit my code in a way that you think it may work as an example?

Comment: sys.stdout is just a file handle that happens to write to standard output (i.e. the screen, or whatever you put after >).  Within the code, you can treat it as a normal filehandle, as if you had written `with open(...,'w') as sys.stdout:`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Visual Studio works, but if it works with `argv[4]` it's probably interpreting every word after the script name like another argument (as it's not bash to have a special interpretation for ">").

So for it to work from bash, you should probably change `argv[4]` in the code to `argv[3]`, and pass the output file as another argument instead of redirecting:

```
python main.py flip pattern.ppm flippedpattern.ppm
```

, or leave the code as it is and add a "dummy" third argument so the output file will be the 4th, for example force it to treat ">" as a regular argument as well:

```
python3 main.py flip pattern.ppm ">" flippedpattern.ppm
```

Comment: I have edited my code - will that route work as well?  I'm not sure how to tackle this issue without changing the input.

Comment: Yes it is empty - used visual studio to test my structure, now using the terminal (vim) and eog to test the output.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you see the desired output in the console if you run it without the redirect?

Comment: With your current code it probably won't work from Visual Studio because of the redirect. So to test the contents of the output file you should run it from terminal. Do you need the same code to work from both?